# What's it called when one is so familiar with a language that phrases just "sound" right or wrong?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, expressions, phrase-requests

Native speakers, especially those who have read a lot of writing or literature for a given language, acquire the ability to "know" whether something is grammatically correct (or not) just from their recognition of patterns and phrases and not necessarily any specific rules of grammar or language usage (i.e. transitive or intransitive verbs, conjugation, etc.)

Is there a term for this?

Comment: People who can do this are said to speak the language natively. This doesn't mean, however, that they can distinguish grammatical rules from politeness rules or socioeconomic class rules without instruction. As we demonstrate all the time here on ELU.

Comment: It is just a matter of pattern recognition or the lack of it.  When we hear the same phrase often enough, we accept it instantly.  If we hear:  "the bird is on the wings", we can instantly recognize something is WRONG.  We don't need to stop and ponder that a bird has two wings and the phrase may be right.

Comment: @Gary: I've never really believed two wrongs make a right, but if you have *enough* "wrongs", they can collectively justify themselves. So this version gets my vote of approval: *Spring is sprung, de grass is ris. I wonders where dem boidies is. Dey say de boids is on de wing. Ain't that absoid! De little wings is on de boid!*

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I love it!!! You have surely earned your poetic license (perhaps even a poetic PhD.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Where does one find such funny poems?

Comment: @rogermue: I heard that one in the school playground over 50 years ago. Since having the luxury of searching the Internet in more recent times, I've discovered that relatively few versions include the "New York Accent" ***boids*** instead of ***birds***, so I'm guessing it didn't necessarily originate in the Big Apple.

Comment: Educated people still argue over what the 'grammatical rules' actually are. It'll take many years before I 'accept' _It's goodnight from Julie and I_, which the BBC grammar police allow. However, I've no problems with _It's us_, _by and large_, _all of a sudden_, _dance attention on someone_, _More than one of the passengers was hurt_ and _A person may waive their right to vote_.

Answer (score 2):

**Sprachgefühl**: [A feeling for language; an ear for the idiomatically correct or appropriate.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sprachgef%C3%BChl)

Answer (score 1):

It is called **[linguistic competence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_competence)**.

> Linguistic competence is the system of linguistic knowledge possessed by native speakers of a language. It is in contrast to the concept of Linguistic performance, the way the language system is used in communication.

Comment: Excellent. That seems like a better term than "native speaker".